# can't install pywin32 --strange error

Tags: python, pip, pywin32

i tried to install pywin32 in Pycharm and in cmd with "pip install pywin32" and i got that massage:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32
```

Comment: See the [unofficial binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32)

Comment: What's the _Python_ version you're using in _PyCharm_?